# Docker Unable to connect to Flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I am trying to move a simple flask application to docker, but my flask application is not accessible from the browser.

project tree

```
├───project
│   │   dockerfile
│   │   requirements.txt
│   │
│   └───app
│           server.py
```

dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app/server.py", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12.2
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask Dockerized'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

docker commands:

```
docker build -t test-server:latest .
```

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 test-server
```

docker logs

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 224-123-338
```

docker --version : `Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea`

docker ps

```
1c54ccfc61bf        test-server         "python app/server.p…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   elated_solomon
```

Comment: Which port is this running on? And are you exposing that port?

Comment: Could you post your docker build and docker run commands as well?

Comment: port 5000 and `docker build -t test-server:latest .` and `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 test-server`

Comment: Are you running this on Docker Toolbox by any chance? Also, have you run a docker logs on the container to see if any error has occurred?

Comment: In my system  * Debugger is active! * Debugger PIN: 224-123-338 this is not coming so the logs are not updating too. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting this to run in debug mode by setting `app.run(debug=True)` shows that the host you think you are setting is getting overridden:

```sh
❰mm92400❙~/test❱✔≻ docker run -it -p 5000:5000 testimage
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 963-222-479
```

So set the host like `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`:

```sh
❰mm92400❙~/test❱✔≻ docker run -it -p 5000:5000 testimage
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 200-559-808
```

And the browser connection works

```sh
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2020 15:59:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Maybe it's not my code the issue but my docker install I'm running docker desktop on windows 10 pro with `Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea` I've update my first post with your suggestions I have always the issue

Comment: Hm, I'm running docker for Mac, version 19.03.5, not sure about the finer details of the differences between the two engines. What may be helpful is to use the official [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) image, as well, this may minimize the differences

Answer (score 0):

I am running Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home and I ran into similar problem too where I was unable to connect my docker deployed flask app using the browser. Here is what yopu can try and should work for you:

In Dockerfile please add-

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

In app.py (your python file)

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Build

```
docker build -t test-server:latest .
```

Run

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 test-server
```

Now, Run below command

```
docker-machine env
```

Check what IP you got for DOCKER_HOST after running the above command(default is 192.168.99.100:2376)

In browser type whatever IP you got for DOCKER_HOST along with port 5000
Ex: http://192.168.99.100:5000

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, here is how i was able to reach the api.

i was running on windows 10. I was able to access using IPV4 address of windows machine with port.

Following are the steps i followed :

1. Open CMD
2. Ipconfig
3. Select IPv4 address and add the port defined in docker run command ( 8080 ) in my case.